Verification of proof: Probability of winning equals probability of losing in a biased coin game
Problem:
We're covering probability in lecture one day, and you volunteer for a demonstration. The professor shows you a coin and says he'll bet you one dollar that the coin will come up heads. Suspecting the coin is biased, such that the probability of a flip coming up heads, $\Pr\{H\}$, is $p$ for $\frac{1}{2} < p \leq 1$, you call him out on this.
The professor offers you a deal: You can come up with an algorithm using the biased coin to simulate a fair coin, such that the probability you win and he loses, $\Pr\{W\}$, is equal to the probability that he wins and you lose, $\Pr\{L\}$.
Your algorithm:

Flip the coin twice
Based on the results:

TH $\Rightarrow$ you win [W], and the game terminates
HT $\Rightarrow$ Professor wins [L], and the game terminates
(HH $\vee$ TT) $\Rightarrow$ discard the result and flip again


If at the end of N rounds nobody has won, declare a tie

For example, with N = 3:

HT would mean the game ends early and you lose
HHTH would mean the game ends early and you win
HHTTT would mean you play the full N rounds and result in a tie

Question: Assume the flips are mutually independent. Show that $\Pr\{W\} = \Pr\{L\}$.
My attempt:
Since the flips are mutually independent, that means $\forall i \in [1,n]$ and $\forall S \subseteq [1,n]-\{i\}$:
$\Pr(E_i|\bigcap_{j \in S} E_j) = \Pr(E_i)$
Let $E_i$ be the event TH, then by above definition:
$\Pr(TH|E_j) = \Pr(TH)$
$\Pr(TH) = (1-p) \cdot p = p(1-p)$
Similarly:
$\Pr(HT|E_j) = \Pr(HT)$
$\Pr(HT) = p \cdot (1-p) = p(1-p)$
Hence $\Pr(W) = \Pr(L)$
I would like to verify if my reasoning and proof are correct?

Well, if you are allowing ties, then a simpler algorithm is to simply declare a tie at the start.  $0=0$, after all.  But, yes.  Regardless of the value of $p$, both $HT$ and $TH$ have a probability of $p(1-p)$.

If you don't allow ties, then you can just let $N$ go to $\infty$.  Not practical, if $p=10^{-100}$ or whatever, but it will still yield a winner (eventually) with probability $1$ unless $p=0$ or $p=1$.

@lulu Thanks for your reply. I checked my answer with solution and it is correct. But I wanted to know if my reasoning is correct as well, in other words is my derivation correct?

Well, as I said, it is clearly true that $P(HT)=P(TH)=p(1-p)$.  Simple consequence of independence.    I don't understand what you wrote, however.  $P(E,|,E)=1$ for any event $E$...what is the conditioning meant to do?

If you want the probability that $TH$, say, wins within $N$ rounds (with a tie after that if noi winner is declared), you can do it recursively.  Let $p_N$ denote this probability and then remark that $p_N=(p^2+(1-p)^2)\times p_{N-1}+ p(1-p)\times 1+p(1-p)\times 0$.  Or simply note that the probability of a tie is $p_t=(p^2+(1-p)^2)^N$ and $ p_N=\frac 12\times (1-p_t)$

@Lulu The question was simply to show that Pr{}=Pr{} . So I was asking if my derivation that Pr(HT) = Pr(TH) = p(1-p) is correct?

As I have said, the claim that $P(TH)=P(HT)=p(1-p)$ is correct and it follows instantly from independence.  I do not understand your calculation, however, as it involves conditioning in some way.
